# Python: Count how often a word of a certain length occurs in a file

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create a list which prints a stat of my text:

My last try so far which i not working.

```
 f = open("input.txt", encoding="utf-8")  
 text = f.read()split()   

 words = []  
 one_l_words = []
 two_l_words = []

 for each in lines:
     words += each.split(" ")

 for each in words:
     if len(each) == 1:
         one_l_word.append(each)

 for each in words:
     if len(each) == 2:
         two_l_word.append(each)

 number_of_1lwords = len(one_l_words)
 number_of_2lwords = len(two_l_words) 


 print(one_l_words) 
 print(two_l_words)
```

The first problem is, that my code is not working but i think anyway i make it to complicated. Because i want to count words from a length 1 until a length of 30 and it should be a simple program.

Basically it should be a list like this:

```
length | How often a word of this length occures
2      12415
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following using a dictionary:

```
f = open("airline.py")
words = f.read().split()
counts = {}
for i in words:
    if len(i) not in counts:
        counts[len(i)] = 1
    else:
        counts[len(i)]+=1

counts = sorted(counts.items(), key=lambda x:x[0]) #Converts to a list of tuples and sorts

print "length\t\tHow often a word of this length occurs"
for j in counts:
    print str(j[0])+"\t\t"+str(j[1])
```

---

**Sample output:**

```
Length  How often a word of this length occurs
1       21
2       7
3       32
4       4
5       11
6       11
7       5
8       13
9       8
10      14
11      10
12      5
13      12
14      9
15      5
17      3
18      6
19      1
20      1
21      3
22      1
27      1
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, but in my output its not sorted. It starts with length 11, 6, ....

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionnary as follow:

```
dico = {}
for i in range(1 ,31): # just to init the dict and avoid checking if index exist...
    dico[i] = 0

with open("input.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f: # better to use in that way
    line = f.read()
    for word in line.split(" "):
        dico[len(word)] += 1   

print(dico)
```

I hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

A [`collections.defaultdict(int)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) would be very suitable in this case:

```py
import collections


def main():
    counts = collections.defaultdict(int)
    with open('input.txt', 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        for word in file.read().split():
            counts[len(word)] += 1
    print('length | How often a word of this length occurs')
    for i in sorted(counts.keys()):
        print('%-6d | %d' % (i, counts[i]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#something like this might work
a = 'aAa@!@121'
d = {}
for i in a:
    d[i]=d.get(i,0)+1

print(d)

#d has characters as key and value will be the count of character present in the string
```